# Checking lock granularity

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, locking

I understand in SQL Server there are various levels of granularity for locks...RID, Key, Page, Extent, Table, DB.

Forgetting about lock escalation, I just want to check the default level of lock granularity in SQL Server 2008? How do I do that?

Comment: In what respect? The default is row (which applies to Key and RID) but it can be changed by escalation, or by table/index options. Also see http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/6512/630 for more

Comment: Ok I assume I have row.  How do I check if any table / index options could have changed this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After comments on questions

You can query [`sys.indexes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173760.aspx), looking at the `allow_row_locks` and `allow_page_locks` columns. Also, [`sys.tables`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187406.aspx) has a column `lock_escalation`

I *think* that will allow you to find all non-default options about locks.